# Intuition behind fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1 {(1+\frac1 n )^n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}(1-\frac1 n)^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Why does

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac1 { \left(1+\frac1 n \right)^n}=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac1 n \right)^n$$

I understand that the math works out because both can be proven to be equal to

$$1-{1\over1!} + {1\over2!} - {1\over3!}... {(-1)^n\over n!}$$

I am just wondering if there is any more intuitive explanation.

Comment: You're aware that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n=e^x$? So you're basically just saying $e^{-x}=\frac1{e^x}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)^n = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^n, $$
which converges to $1$ (take logs, or use the binomial theorem with a remainder term, or Bernoulli's inequalities...)

Comment: Rigorously speaking, this proves $\lim_n (a_n/b_n) = 1$ but not $\lim_n a_n = \lim_n b_n$.

Comment: True, but one can show that one is increasing and bounded above while the other is decreasing and bounded below, to show that the individual limits exist in the first place.

Comment: @Chappers, would you mind just pointing me to the relevant wikipedia or stackexchange page where I can find proof of $(x+y)^n(x-y)^n=(x^2-y^2)^n$

Comment: @agblt It's just $a^nb^n = (ab)^n$ ($n$ is an integer, so this is provable by induction, if you like), and then difference of two squares in reverse.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: @Zhanxiong: it does prove that if one sequence converges to $l$ the other also converges to the same limit $l$. And convergence of $(1+n^{-1})^n$ is well known.

Answer (score 3):

It's a matter of simple algebra. Just note that $$\left(1-\frac {1}{n}\right)^n=\dfrac{1}{\left(\dfrac{n}{n-1}\right)^n}=\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}}$$ Taking limit gives you the desired equality. Using the same technique (and slightly more effort) you can prove that if $x$ is a rational number then $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=\left(\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) ^n\right) ^x$$ (your current question being about $x=-1$).

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{n}{n+1} = 1-\frac{1}{n+1}$$
and $\left( 1-\frac{1}{n+1} \right)^n$ and $\left( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right)^n$ behave the same way in the limit. Notice that $\frac{1} { \left(1+\frac1 n \right)^n}=\left( \frac{1} { 1+\frac1 n } \right)^n$ so I can do this.